# D3: Giving a linear scale a dynamic domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**NOTE:** We're still using v3 of D3, so v4 stuff doesn't help :(

I'm trying to draw 2 separate charts using the same code in a modularized fashion, while passing the data as a param.

It's all working beautifully in the code below, ***except for one little thing....***

I am currently using `data1.length` to calculate the `domain` for `xScale`. I want to be able to pass in a param there (e.g. `dataSource`) so that I can set it dynamically.

Here's a handy little JSFiddle if you'd like to code out a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/8zpd79yp/

TIA

```
var data1 = [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9];
var data2 = [9, 5, 2, 8, 3, 1, 7, 4, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3];

var width = 800; 
var height = 400; 

var graph = d3.select(".graph");

var container = graph.append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("padding", "10px")
      .classed("container", true);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, data1.length])
  .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i); 
  })
  .y(function(d) { 
    return yScale(d); 
  })

function drawChart(dataSource) {
  var chart = graph.select(".container")
    .append("g")
    .append("path")
      .attr("d", line(dataSource));
}

drawChart(data1);
drawChart(data2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define xScale like this, sans the domain.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width]);
```

This will set the xScale domain dynamic

```
function drawChart(dataSource) {
      xScale.domain([0, dataSource.length]);        
      var chart = graph.select(".container")
        .append("g")
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", line(dataSource));
    }
```

So now when you call:

```
   drawChart(data1);
   drawChart(data2);
```

The domain of the xScale will be set dynamically.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8od76ryf/)

Comment: Works. May the universe smile on you with endless benevolence. aka thanks =)